# Firefox table sticky header row events not firing

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-table

I have a simple HTML table with a sticky header row. The header cell has a mouse enter event attached to it. In `Firefox`, the event stops firing when the user has **scrolled down**. This occurs ONLY when there are 21 rows (counting header) or more.

I have tested this in Chrome and Safari where this functionality appears to work correctly. I do not understand why this problem is occurring in `Firefox`.

```js
const stickyRows = document.getElementsByClassName('sticky-row');
Array.from(stickyRows).forEach((stickyRowElement) => {
  stickyRowElement.children[0].onmouseenter = () => console.log('mouse enter cell');
});
```

```css
td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

.sticky-row {
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div style="max-height: 300px; overflow: scroll">
  <table style="float:left">
    <tr class="sticky-row"><th>Sticky header for 20 rows</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 9</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 10</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 11</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 12</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 13</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 14</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 15</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 16</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 17</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 18</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 19</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 20</td></tr>
  </table>

  <table>
    <tr class="sticky-row"><th>Sticky header for 21 rows</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 9</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 10</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 11</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 12</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 13</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 14</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 15</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 16</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 17</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 18</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 19</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 20</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Row 21</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're not creating brand new elements from in-memory, never use `on`* handlers. Always use `.addEventListener()`

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't fix the problem, but thankyou for the recommendation. May I ask what advantage does this carry?

Comment: Copy paste those three lines, change the log message. You'll immediately understand why it's bad practice. You'll only the the log of the second one - since it overrides the first one.

Comment: Your snippet works perfectly fine in Firefox.

Comment: I have tested this in 3 different computers with the latest Firefox version ```108``` and also ```107``` and this issue was present in all of them. If you are not seeing it, make sure you scroll down in the overflow div and if it helps view the snippet in ```Full page``` mode and observe if the events are fired in the browser console.